# How to speed up the process of generating model in GAMS

Tags: gams-math

I am using GAMS to solve a nonlinear programming problem. The problem size is about 500K rows, 500k columns, and 1M non-zeros. I found that it took long time to generate the model, sometimes even longer than solving the model. Are there any ways to speed up the generating process inside GAMS? Alternatively, if I switch to other platforms, are there any good choices to resolve this issue? Thanks.

Comment: This question is very general, so here is a link to some general hints: https://support.gams.com/gams:how_to_reduce_model_generation_time 

Also, the profile parameter (https://www.gams.com/33/docs/UG_GamsCall.html#GAMSAOprofile) might be helpful for you.

Comment: @Lutz this is very helpful, thank you!